# Question about refraction in a swimming pool

Tags: visible-light, refraction

When you are at the bottom of a swimming pool with lane lines at the bottom of the pool, you can see the lane lines at the surface of the pool as well. Can someone explain why this occurs? I know it has something to do with refraction but I don't know how it happens exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Generally when you’re underwater and look straight up, you do not notice your reflection. It’s there, but drowned out by all the light coming through from above. For the same reason, you don’t see your reflection when you look out a window in the daytime (even though it’s there, as you can verify by looking at the same window pane at night when the illumination is only on your side).

In the underwater case though, the light you see coming through from above is passing from a low-index medium (air) to a higher-index one (water). This means that the light effectively slows down and bends toward the vertical when it crosses the interface (the “refraction” mentioned in the question; you can learn how much bending occurs by looking up Snell’s Law). When you look at the surface from underwater at an angle rather than straight up, the light you see coming through from above is coming from a larger angle from the vertical due to the bending. Beyond the critical angle (for water [index 1.33] into air [index 1] it’s about 49 degrees from the vertical) at which the bending means that light coming from above would need to be coming in directly from the side, none of the light you see comes through the surface. Similarly, beyond this angle, all of the light rays forming the image reflect—in order to transmit they would need to refract further than horizontal. This is called total internal reflection, and it makes for very distinct images since all the light rays from the object reflect and there are no competing rays coming through the surface to obscure them.

So, the reason the lane line images are there is simply reflection, as with a mirror. The reasons they’re so vivid are that at sufficiently large angles, none of the image intensity is lost to transmission and rays of light from above the interface are completely suppressed.

Comment: but doesnt TIR occur only when light goes from a medium with a high RI to a low RI? i think your explanation is wrong.

Comment: The light that makes the image on your retina of the lane lines starts at the bottom of the swimming pool. That’s in the high index medium. It travels upward at an angle until it encounters the interface with the air (the low index medium). It undergoes total internal reflection and proceeds at a downward angle until it enters your pupil. Which part of this confuses you?

Comment: oh wait nevermind it all makes sense now. sorry youre right, i'm just dumb haha.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection, not refraction. The water:air interface is reflective from both directions.

Comment: sorry, could you explain this is in a little more detail? thanks